# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'decimal.Decimal' and 'dict'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. I tried to convert highest_bid to a float:

highest_bid = float(Bid.objects.filter(id=bid_item.id).aggregate(Max('bid_input')))

but that also produced an error because a dict cannot be converted to a float in that way. So I'm not sure how to resolve this. I'm trying to build an auctions site and I would like the bid that a user places to be rejected if it is less than the listing start price and less than the highest of all the bids that have been placed.

**error**

```
Internal Server Error: /listing/2/bid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python385\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 157, in placebid
    if bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input'] < listing.start_price and bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input'] <= highest_bid:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'decimal.Decimal' and 'dict'
[08/Oct/2020 13:59:48] "POST /listing/2/bid HTTP/1.1" 500 62598
```

**views.py**

```
def placebid(request, id):
    listing_bid = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=id)
    highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        bidform = BidForm(request.POST)
        if bidform.is_valid():
            if bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input'] < listing.start_price and bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input'] <= highest_bid:
                return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
                    "listing": listing,
                    "error": "Make sure your bid is greater than the start price and current highest bid"
                    })
            else:
                listing_bid.bid_input = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
                listing_bid.bidder = request.user
                listing_bid.bid_item = listing
                listing_bid.time = timezone.now()
                listing_bid.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
                "bidform": bidform })
    else:
        bidform = BidForm()
    return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
        "bidform": bidform })
```

Please let me know if I need to include any more details.

**Edited to add: models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    class NewManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset().filter(status='active')

    options = (
        ('active', 'Active'),
        ('closed', 'Closed'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=64)
    start_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.99)])
    image = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
    lister = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True, related_name="lister_user")
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default="active")
    winner = models.ForeignKey('Bid', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="bid_winner")
    favourites = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="favourite", default=None, blank=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    listingmanager = NewManager()

    def __str__(self): 
        return f"{self.title} ({self.pk}, £{self.start_price}, {self.lister})"


class Bid(models.Model):
    bidder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bidders")
    bid_item = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bid_items", default=None)
    bid_input = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=None)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bidder}, bid amount: {self.bid_input}"
```

**Edited to add: updated views.py**

```
def placebid(request, id):
    listing_bid = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=id)
    highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max'] or Decimal('0')
    listing = Listing.objects.get(pk=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        bidform = BidForm(request.POST)
        if bidform.is_valid():
            if bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input'] < listing.start_price and bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input'] <= highest_bid:
                return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
                    "listing": listing,
                    "error": "Make sure your bid is greater than the start price and current highest bid"
                })
            else:
                newbid = bidform.save(commit=False)
                newbid.bidder = request.user
                newbid.bid_input = bidform.cleaned_data['bid_input']
                newbid.bid_item = listing_bid
                newbid.time = timezone.now()
                newbid.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Bid placed succesfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing", args=(id,)))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
                "bidform": bidform })
    else:
        bidform = BidForm()
    return render(request, "auctions/listingPage.html", {
        "bidform": bidform })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`highest_bid` is a dictionary that maps the name of the aggregate to a value, so for example `{ 'bid_input__max': Decimal('14.25') }`, you can thus unwrap the value from the dictionary by subscripting:

```
highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(
    id=id
).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']
```

but likely this will not give you the expected value. You filter on `id=id`, so that means the queryset spans *one* records. You probably want to filter over the `bid_item_id=id` or something similar:

```
highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(
    bid_item_id=id
).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']
```

based on your comment, it is possible that there is no bid yet. In that case, it will return a `None`. We can use zero instead with:

```
highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(
    bid_item_id=id
).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']  or Decimal('0')
```

Comment: Thank you, so I tried your second suggestion first and the error came up as: `FieldError at /listing/2/bid
Cannot resolve keyword 'listing_id' into field. Choices are: bid_input, bid_item, bid_item_id, bid_winner, bidder, bidder_id, id, time` and when I leave it as id=id, the error comes up as: `'<=' not supported between instances of 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: @sarchi-xo: how is a `Bid` related to a `Listing`? Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: @sarchi-xo: then it is `bid_item_id=id`.

Comment: sadly this returns the same error: `'<=' not supported between instances of 'decimal.Decimal' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: @sarchi-xo: but did you add the `['bid_input__max']` at the end?

Comment: @sarchi-xo: the `None`-type however means there was simply no bid at that moment. You can make use of an `...  or ...` expression to replace it with zero. See edit.

Comment: yes the full line is: `highest_bid = Bid.objects.filter(bid_item_id=id).aggregate(Max('bid_input'))['bid_input__max']`. And that is a good point, I'm not sure how to code so that in the case highest_bid is None then just make sure bid_input is > listing.start_price

Comment: @sarchi-xo: you can add `... or Decimal('0')` at the end to use `0` in case there is no bid (yet).

Comment: thank you!! yes, I just saw your edit. That has gotten rid of the django error but now I've run straight into another problem of the bid not being stored in the Bids model. I checked in \admin and there are 0 bids even after I've just placed several bids

Comment: @sarchi-xo: but you are only *editing* the `listing_bid` object. Which is a `Listing` object, not even a `Bid` object. Likely you should create a new `Bid` object.

Comment: By storing this in the `Listing` you introduce also *data duplication*, which often is a harder problem than one expects: synchronizing data, even on the same database, is suprisingly hard. I think you might want to create a *new* `Bid` object.

Comment: Okay, I think I am following you. Instead of listing_bid = get_object_or_404... I changed it to `listing_bid, created = Bid.objects.get_or_create(bid_item_id=id)` but this produced an integrity error: IntegrityError at /listing/2/bid
NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_bid.bid_input`

Comment: @sarchi-xo: no you should create a *new* `Bid` with all necessary fields. Not at the head of the view, but when validation is done. so in this case in the `else` block. You can not create an object without all necessary fields. Furthermore by using `get_or_create`, you are *only* creating a new bid if no other bid for that `Listing` is present, so in case there is, you will (again) edit the existing one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience with me, it seems the problem is now resolved! I did what you said and created a new bid in the else block, I edited my question with the updated views.py so you can see. I'm sure I'll run into another problem again soon but thank you for helping me resolve this one :)